# Can the limit of a complex number have multiple values?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I have been studying "Complex analysis" for a while. In this "limit of complex function" question, I get an answer that's a $4$th root of $-1.$ I change  that form to polar coordinate form and then see that there's more than one value. This is the work that I have done so far:

[image]

So,

1. Can the limit of a complex function has more than one value?
2. If not, do I need to change an answer that's a fractional exponent to polar form?

Comment: No, the limit is unique, since the topology on $\mathbb{C}$ is Hausdorff..

Comment: @Cornman Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please put your equations in the question directly, rather than linking an image. It looks like the image came from MathJax or LaTeX anyway, so you can paste the code for the equations into the question, inside `$`...`$` in a paragraph or `$$`...`$$` for a full equation just like in LaTeX.

Comment: You brought additional solutions into the picture by using $e^{\pi i/4} = (e^{\pi i})^{1/4}$. There are four complex numbers $z$ with $z^4 = -1$, but only one of them is $e^{\pi i/4}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for suggestion. @aschepler P.S. I used "MathType" for typing equations. So I'll try to use LaTeX next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The limit, when it exists, is unique. In your case, you have\begin{align}\require{cancel}\lim_{z\to e^{\pi i/4}}\frac{z^2}{z^4+z+1}&=\frac{e^{\pi i/2}}{\cancel{e^{\pi i}}+e^{\pi i/4}+\cancel1}\\&=\frac{e^{\pi i/2}}{e^{\pi i/4}}\\&=e^{\pi i/4}\\&=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}.\end{align}

Your mistake lies in the equality $e^{\pi i/4}=\left(e^{\pi i}\right)^{1/4}$.

Comment: Oh! I forget that e^(xi)=cos(x)+isin(x)
Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 6):

1. As has been pointed out, your first equality contains the mistake $$(e^{\pi i})^{1/4}\color{red}=e^{\pi i/4}.$$ The LHS are the four $4$th roots of $-1,$ while the RHS is the single value $\displaystyle\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}.$
2. In general, the law $$\large(e^z)^n=e^{nz}$$ holds for $$z\in\mathbb C,\,n\in\mathbb Z$$ and, separately, for $$z,n\in\mathbb R.$$
3. Multiple values are created not by converting a complex number to polar form per se, but by raising it to the power $\displaystyle\frac1n$ (obtaining its $n$th roots).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful to me for better understanding!